# use a string from edit text in my keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I'm playing around with softkeyboard.

i added this to preferences

```
<EditTextPreference
android:name="Custom ket"
android:summary="Set up a custom key"
android:title="Custom key"
android:key="Customkey" />
```

what do I have to do to use this as a string in

```
<Key android:keyOutputText="string" android:keyLabel="custom key" />
```

can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working

Added to SoftKeyboard.java

```
private void handleCustomkey() {
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
            getSharedPreferences("com.keyboard.test_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String ck = app_preferences.getString("Customkey", "0");
    this.getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(ck, 1);


    }
```

@ onkey

```
    } else if (primaryCode == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_CUSTOMKEY) {
        handleCustomkey();
        return;
```

add to LatinKeyboardView.java

```
static final int KEYCODE_CUSTOMKEY = -120;
```

add to qwerty.xml

```
    <Key android:codes="-120" android:keyLabel="Custom" />
```

add to settings.xml

```
<EditTextPreference
android:name="Custom key"
android:summary="Set up a custom key"
android:title="Custom key"
android:key="Customkey" />
```